# installing software without sudo locally

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo, pip

I have no admin rights but need to install programs. I read there is the way to install it locally but I did not find minimal example for one program (let it be for example vim or opencv).

How could I do it using apt-get install or using pip and what is the practical difference in comparison to installation with admin rights?

Comment: Installing something usually implies permanence.

Comment: Pip is only for Python packages. If you need packages for other languages, then you need to hunt down the package managers they use.

Comment: Talk to your boss and get sudo privaledges. If s/ he says no then s.he has their reasons. This is more a legal or business ethics question than Ubuntu.

Comment: In this context, having the program "installed locally" typically means installing to your home directory, where you have write permission. Without the necessary privileges, you can't install system-wide.

Comment: @bgse thank you, what is the way to install to home directory? In the forum I found answers containing many steps, is that this complicated? What would be the difference if it is local install?

Comment: @beginh That depends on the software, for software that comes in tar.gz archives, it is sometimes enough to just copy the contents into a directory in your homedir. The usual difference to a system-wide install would be that the software is not available for all users, only to the owner of the installation and the users that have at least read and execute privileges on it.

Comment: You are given some answers now. If any one of them answered you question you might consider accepting or solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you're installing software for all users, in other words writing in system area, you will always need the `sudo` password (unless the configuration is changed for you by an admin). However, If you want to use your own software, you have several options.

1. Compile and build the software from source and installing it in userspace.
2. Finding portable versions of softwares

For portable applications, You can have a look [AppImages](https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages).

Usually they contain the dependencies within themselves, thus making it good for a single file package format. You download an application and run it by double clicking it. No need to install. **Another advantage** is, most of the time you will get the latest version of an application which is not yet available in Ubuntu repositories.

The downside of these applications are they are usually bigger in size. Another is they can't always integrate well with the existing system. They run from a separate isolated environment. As a result, often when you want to save files, the default location shown would be different from your home directory. Another sad news is, only the popular GUI applications are available in this format.

Here are some AppImage applications for example

- [Clementine](https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages/Clementine)
- [Brackets](https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages/Brackets)
- [Chromium](https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages/Chromium)

Answer (score 2):

Compile the software from source with `make` and then run the resulting build.

That should be close enough.

Otherwise add each of the installs to you PATH variable.

Answer (score 2):

For Python you can do so by using:

```
pip install --user XXX
```

where `XXX` is the package you want to install.